# tikz exact text position along 3 intersecting circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikzlibrary

i'am not able to correctly place a text string along the perimeter of 3 circles that I've produced using tikz together with the decorations.text library.

This is what i've got till now

[image]

Clearly, the text is completely offset, I need text A and B specular in the top right of the circle while Text C at the bottom of its circle. Also I would like to colour the intersection of the three circle with some shade of gray. Here is my code

```
\draw[ultra thick, -stealth,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text A}, text align=left, reverse path,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white, yshift=-0.5ex}}}]
  (1.5, 0) circle [radius=4];

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick, -stealth,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text B}, text align=center, reverse path,
        text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white, xshift=2ex, yshift=-0.5ex}}}]
  (-1.5, 0) circle [radius=4];

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick, -stealth,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text C}, text align=right,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white, yshift=-0.5ex}}}]
  (0, -3) circle [radius=4];

\node[draw=none,text width=2.5cm] at (0.5,-0.9) { Some other T};




\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that there is a `-stealth` directive, which gets suppressed, well, because as circle is a circle. So If you switch to `arc`s instead, you can have both: easier positioning of the text and have the arrow. <s>The price you pay is that you have to feed in the starting point of the arc, not the center of the circle.</s> **UPDATE**: You can keep the center coordinates and I place the arrows using another decoration (and I also remove the `xshift` which makes the thing look asymmetric, and replaced `yshift` by `raise`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}


\draw[ultra thick, 
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text A}, text align=center, reverse path,raise=-0.5ex,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}},
      postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,{mark=at position 0.25 with
      {\arrow{stealth}}}}}]
  (1.5, 2)+(-90:4) arc(-90:270:4);

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick, 
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text B}, text align=center, reverse path,raise=-0.5ex,
        text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}},
      postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,{mark=at position 0.75 with
      {\arrow{stealth}}}}}]
  (-1.5, 2)+(-90:4) arc(-90:270:4);

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,raise=-0.5ex,
    text={Some text C}, text align=center,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}},
      postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,{mark=at position 0.25 with
      {\arrow{stealth}}}}}]
  (0,-3)+(90:4) arc(90:450:4);

\node[draw=none,text width=2.5cm] at (0.5,-0.9) { Some other T};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, another way: just rotate the full thing and adjust the rotation angle to define the text position and without arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]


\draw[ultra thick,rotate around={225:(1.5,2)},
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text A}, text align=center, reverse path,raise=-0.5ex,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}}]
  (1.5, 2) circle(4);

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick,rotate around={315:(-1.5,2)}, 
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={Some text B}, text align=center, reverse path,raise=-0.5ex,
        text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}}]
  (-1.5, 2) circle(4);

\draw[draw=black, ultra thick,rotate around={90:(0,-3)},
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,raise=-0.5ex,
    text={Some text C}, text align=center,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white}}}]
  (0,-3) circle(4);

\node[draw=none,text width=2.5cm] at (0.5,-0.25) { Some other T};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, is there a way to get rid of the arrow? Otherwise, this solution would not work for my problem

Comment: @AlbertoStefanelli Absolutely. I thought you wanted the arrow since you had `-stealth` in your `\draw` commands. Just remove `postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,{mark=at position 0.25 with
      {\arrow{stealth}}}}}` from the `\draw` commands.